# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS /etc/resolv.conf is getting overwritten after either netplan apply or server reboot and not able access DNS

Tags: resolv.conf

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS `/etc/resolv.conf` is getting overwritten after either netplan apply or server reboot. We are not using networkmanager.

We did the following changes not sure if this will help:

```
sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
```

Add DNS in netplan and do `sudo netplan apply`.

Answer (score 1):

As the `/etc/resolv.conf` said, you shouldn't edit that file as is managed by Systemd.
Add your DNS configuration on `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. A better practice would not be editing the original configuration file but create another one, like `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf`

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

Remember to restart the service with `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`

Comment: thanksAs the /etc/resolv.conf said, you shouldn't edit that file as is managed by Systemd. Add your DNS configuration on /etc/systemd/resolved.conf. A better practice would not be editing the original configuration file but create another one, like /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf

[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 ---> can i add my namesserver
Remember to restart the service with sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved

Comment: Yes, you can add whatever DNS you want.

Comment: thanks we dont have network manager, i hope this will work